# Slider background absolute position - Firefox error

Tags: css, firefox, slider

Developing a small website for a restaurant i stumbled upon this weird issue with positioning in Firefox - IE & Chrome works flawlessly.

URL: [Café website](http://cafe-victoriaodense.dk/)

The slider is positioned as:

```
#new-royalslider-1{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1
```

Its pretty simple, can anybody figure out why Firefox is behaving differently?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the styling of the menu

Comment: I agree with @Frederik the issue seems to be position of the navigation in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should position your slider relative and put the header wrapper inside. Positioned absolute.

If you don't want to do that you can do `position: relative` with the slider and the following with the header wrapper

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but it seems like html is truncated. So, I firebugged :  `html{float: left}`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now define your **id** `#header-wrapper` `position absolute` as like this

```
#header-wrapper{position:absolute;top:0;}
```

and define your **id** `#wrapper` `margin-top: 450px;` **as like this**

```
#wrapper {
    margin-top: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All browsers do not display a website in the same way and even if the whole tends to unite, there are still some points of detail which are misinterpreted by one or the other.

The problem is that Firefox, Opera and Safari do not have a method to assign a separate style sheet, like Internet Explorer, with specific comments.

Perhaps by targeting the browser will solve your problem. Add this code:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
    #new-royalslider-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a confusion with the `.header` selector, I see it appearing twice in debug mode and it is not exactly the same that is used in firefox.

In firefox, the problem is solved when you uncheck this rule :

```
.header {
    ...
    ...
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
```

For some reasons, chrome doesn't get the `medium` mention. Hope this helps